# Field required a bean of type ... that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

In my `Spring` project I have an interface:

```
public interface MyIntefrace {

    void myMethod(String myParam);
}
```

and I have a class that implements it:

```
@Component
@Profile("prod")
public class MyImplementationClass implements MyInterface {
    ...
```

In my other class, I'm using this object as follows:

```
@Autowired
MyInterface myinterface;

...

myinterface.myMethod(someParam);
```

And it throws me an error:

```
Field myinterface in mypackage required a bean of type ... that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Consider defining a bean of type '...' in your configuration
```

I tried to add `@Service` annotation above `MyInterface` but that didn't help. What else can I do?

Comment: how your spring components are scanned?

Comment: How do you start the application? You defined the Component to be available in profile "prod". Did you enable that profile?

e.g. `--spring.profiles.active=prod` as command line argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the `prod` profile is enable such as through :

1. JVM property :

   `-Dspring.profiles.active=prod`
2. Or environment variable:

   `export spring_profiles_active=prod`
3. Or programmatically when creating `ApplicationContext`:

   ```
   AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
   //...........
   ctx.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("prod");
   ctx.refresh();
   ```

Comment: You can also add it to the `application.properties` file, using `spring.profiles.active=prod`.

Comment: Well , `application.properties` is from spring-boot . I don't see @randomuser1 add `spring-boot` tag , so i assume it is a non spring-boot app and I suspect if `application.properties` will work in spring out of the box...

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @KenChan already mentioned a viable solution, but i wanted to add some additional details. Currently, you only have one implementation of `MyIntefrace`, which is also annotated with `@Profile`. If you don not run you application using this profile, all other beans that depend on that bean (and are not optionally injected using getter/setter injection) can not be created.

I recommend you either create a second implementation that will be injected if your profile is not activated, or annotate all depending beans as well with that profile.

```
@Component
@Profile("prod")
public class MyImplementationClass implements MyInterface {
    // ...
}

@Component
@Profile("!prod") // second implementation, used if 'prod' is not active
public class MyImplementationClass implements MyInterface {
    // ...
}
```